# Correct affiliate link for the users iTunes store (us, uk, de, ...)

Tags: ios, app-store, locale

I want to use TradeDoubler (Europe) and LinkShare (US, Canada) in an iPhone app and link to the app store. I already know that I always will be taken to the right store. But the affiliate links are built differently for each country/ program. Therefore I need to know to which store it will take me BEFORE I build the URL.

The users locale doesn't seam to be the right way to do this. For example: I'm in Germany with an iPad that is set up with an US iTunes account. The language is set to English. The locale gives me DE. But I need to search the US store and use LinkShare instead of TradeDoubler links.

Does someone know a way to find out in which iTunes store the user is logged in on a device?

Comment: mmh got a -1 after 2 minutes, am I missing something obvious? I've read a lot of threads and nobody talked about that special problem

Comment: I have upvoted the question, as it is clearly written. The solution might be to use a Settings function inside your app to choose which country user is in or to detect the IP address to set the country for user automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I already considered a solution like this. But I hoped there would be a way to get this information in another , easier way (easier for the user I mean...).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do it manually you can use [Afflr](http://www.afflr.com), it does exactly what you want automatically, you just need to provide it with a link to your app and the ID of your Linkshare and Tradedoubler programs.

Comment: Not sure why this is attracting down-votes. Down-votes are fine but at least give some constructive criticism in a comment!

Comment: Because it uses a geo IP database which isn't guaranteed to get them to the right store either.